# Making a webapp, I need a loading div in between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I'm looking everywhere, but I cant find how to do it!

I have a webapp, and one page is very heavy with data and it takes a long time to load. Is it possible to make a loading div appear when its loading the next page? Maybe like this;

1. Make a loading div, set style to visiblilty: hidden
2. When a user click a link, the div is set to visibilty: visible
3. Starts loading the data of the next page
4. When data loads, the page is shown.

Comment: I havent tried anything. Because I have NO IDEA how to do it lol

Comment: What is your "web app" made with?

Comment: In theory, you are building with an MVC framework, in which case you would know javascript. on click, You would load a div to cover the screen... fade out the current stuff - then request the page data with AJAX or something and grab the JSON or whatever you have --- then with a callback - fade in the new data when it's all loaded. This is a lot of stuff to teach someone in here, and I'm just learning it myself. I'll post a simple version and maybe it will help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, this is just a basic version of what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/CbF9M/

### HTML (just some stuff)

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem amet earum sapiente aspernatur optio aliquid officia veritatis quaerat eaque ex fugiat maiores iure! Fugit deserunt enim cumque eum veniam eius.</p>

<div class="cover"></div>
```

## CSS

```
.cover {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$(window).ready( function() {

    $(".cover").delay(3000).fadeOut();

});
```

So, when the window is loaded... fade out the covering div... but really - you would want to be much more specific about what is loaded. The delay is just for effect, because we don't have any real data being transferred.